# Logistic Regression return only 0 on test but accuracy is high

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, kaggle

I created a Logistic Regression for heart prediction using kaggle's dataset
and whenever I predict output with the test dataset I get only predictions below 0.5 which turns to 0 after the threshold.
But even though the **ALL** the predictions are equal to 0, the accuracy is above 80%.

Why all my predictions are 0?

Here is the Kaggle notebook:
https://www.kaggle.com/code/shaunq/notebook70c0b1571d

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not unexpected that your accuracy is very high, even though you only predict 0. This is because the majority of your training data consists of data that is labeled with 0 (no heart disease). So if the model always predicts 0, it is doing "fairly well".

For how to fix the issue. You could lower the threshold or experiment with different combinations of epochs and learning rate. But know that you are not fair off.

Using the sklearn implementation of Logistic Regression, I get fairly similar results:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from collections import Counter

model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(train_x, train_y)
pred_y = model.predict(test_x)
print(Counter(pred_y))
print(accuracy_score(test_y, pred_y))
```

returns

```
Counter({0: 722, 1: 10})
0.8415300546448088
```